# clickable divisions with dynamic model names using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to create clickable dynamic divs . currently i am using below code to do it.
my service

```
export class ReserveService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getLockers(): Observable<Lockers[]> {
    return this.http.get<Lockers[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums');

  }

}
```

component code

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadLockers();
  }

 loadLockers() {
this.availableLockers = this.reserveService.getLockers();
```

}

Please check above code. I am using below html to loop it

```
      <a *ngFor="let locker of availableLockers | async" class="col-md-3 p-3 m-3 success"
                            contenteditable="true" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: brown;">
                            <label>
                                <input id="lk{{locker.id}}" [value]='locker.id' type="radio" name="locker"
                                    checked="false" [(ngModel)]="locker.id">
                                {{locker.title}}
                            </label>
                        </a>
```

currently all working well. but thing is when I click the div, radio button did not checked. How i do it? or do you know any proper technique for these time of requirement.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a tag you can use a div tag and do the following -

```
<div *ngFor="let locker of availableLockers | async; let index = index" class="col-md-3 p-3 m-3 success"
                            contenteditable="true" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: brown;" (click)="currentSelection = index">
                            <label>
                                <input [value]='locker.id' type="radio" name="locker"
                                    [checked]="getCurrentSelection(index)">
                                {{locker.title}}
                            </label>
                        </div>
```

In the Component Ts file =>

```
currentSelection :number

getCurrentSelection=(indexSelected)=>{
return currentSelection == indexSelected
}
```

Comment: my other form models going with 'reserve', ex: reserve.address, reserve.city.. therefor i need to put [(ngModel)]="reserve.locker". I checked your code and change model as reserve.locker. but model value did not pass .

Comment: remove locker id and ngmodel and try

Comment: that data is basically for current selection data right..?

Comment: yes i need to pass selected radio button value using [(ngModel)]="reserve.locker"

Comment: I have edited my answer please try that code

Comment: where the radio button model. ??? without it, i can not pass the value to the component

Comment: [(ngModel)]="reserve.locker" is must :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233281/discussion-between-jesvin-palatty-and-kumara).